# opscenter upgrade to 5.1.1 keeps failing to upgrade agents

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

i'm running DSE 4.6.1 with opscenter 5.1.0.

i upgraded (through deb package) to opscenter 5.1.1, in the webUI now it says my agents are old (5.1.0) and need to be upgraded, when i try to upgrade through the webUI it says it finished succesfully but actually nothing happened, the agents continue to be 5.1.0.

I've try to upgrade the datastax-agent through apt but it fails also.

any ideas? i was planning to upgrade to 4.6.4 and 5.1.1 this morning but got stuck with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced the same problem yesterday!  You can resolve this issue by following these steps:

1. Check your datastax-agent share directory ( default: **/usr/share/datastax-agent** )
2. Ensure **datastax-agent-5.1.1-standalone.jar** is present.  If it is and **datastax-agent-5.1.0-standalone.jar** is present, delete the 5.1.0 jar file.
3. Restart the datastax-agent service and check that OpsCenter is seeing the correct agent version, if not, continue to the next step!
4. Manually update: /etc/init.d/datastax-agent from it's original form to:  http://pastebin.com/x72vWdQK  (This is the base datastax-agent init script for 5.1.1)

You will want to restart the datastax-agent service after completing these steps!

**Note:**  The above method resolved two issues for me.  The first being your issue upon upgrading OpsCenter to 5.1.1 with the agents not updating appropriately and the second issue involving backups not having appropriate  access to store in the datastax-agent/tmp folder. It appears that the latest release has a few bugs regarding deployment.

Major thanks to **nickmbailey** at the freenode IRC #cassandra channel for working through this with me!

Comment: it worked with the first 3 steps. it appear that the issue was that i was using a datastax-agent 5.1.0-patched jar file (for a fix with the opscenter backup that was fixed in this realease, and so the opscenter wasn't able to delete the old jar. thanks so much for your help

Comment: Great to hear!  Be sure to check your backup service to ensure that the service is receiving the appropriate access to conduct backups (if not, step 4 will resolve it!)

Answer (score 0):

Fix agents via the webUI then

1. cd /usr/share/datastax-agent and chown the 5.1.1 standalone jar (make it the same as the previous standalone jar file)
2. rm or mv the old standalone jar
3. edit /usr/share/datastax-agent/conf/datastax-agent-env.sh to look like this:
   `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xmx128M"
   JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djclouds.mpu.parts.magnitude=100000"
   JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djclouds.mpu.parts.size=16777216"`

Otherwise the agent won't be able to save to S3 properly. You will see OOM errors if you don't make the changes in #3.

EDIT - thanks to commenter. I posted a different question about java out-of-memory errors (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377036/2560922) which led me to discover that datastax-agent-env.sh was not updated in my system. datastax-agent-sudoers was not installed either and ownership of datastax-agent was not changed from opscenter-agent to cassandra.

Comment: Why do you need #3?  Your environment probably isn't setup correctly.  The question that was asked shouldn't require any steps in addition to my original answer. (DataStax defaults for those should be sufficient or your previously set configuration should suffice).  I didn't make any of the adjustments you mentioned and my OpsCenter 5.1.1 backs up to S3 perfectly.  DSE Default is already:  `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xmx128M -Djclouds.mpu.parts.magnitude=100000 -Djclouds.mpu.parts.size=16777216"`
You should probably give credit to the person that told you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29377036/2560922